# The override of imported function

Tags: haskell

I want to import Category and include it's function (.)

And then, I'll use

```
import Data.Function hiding ((.))
import Control.Category
import Prelude hiding ((.))
```

So, I should type `hiding ((.))` twice. If I'll import more module, I may type more.

Is there exist a more elegant way to import `Control.Category`

Comment: you can always use `(>>>)` instead of `(.)`. One other way would be to `import qualified Control.Category as CAT` and then use `CAT..` - but I don't see the point (pun intended) of importing all parts of Function and Category, usually I only need a few bits which I list explicitly, or import the whole module qualified

Comment: IMO this is a non-problem. `Data.Function` defines `.`, and `Prelude` re-exports it because, well, it’s the `Prelude`. It re-exports things. However, it’s pretty unlikely that other modules would re-export `.` from `Data.Function`, so I think “If I'll import more module, I may type more” is an unsubstantiated fear. If you wanted to get rid of one more `hiding`, you could use a custom prelude, but otherwise there’s not really getting around these two.

Comment: The only things in `Data.Function` that aren't in `Prelude` are `(&)` `on` and `fix`. Why not just import whichever of them you need?

Comment: @AlexisKing    So，Only `Prelure` will repeat the import of the module. So I should only `import Prelure hiding (functions)` and `import ModuleName (x,y,andOtherNeedFunctions) `.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe `>>>` and `.` have different infix level. (I wonder if there is a function has the same infix level with `(.)` and has the same infix level with `flip (.)`)